# How to automate the build process so that on each Publish/Unpublish/update/delete content in Contenful will not need a gatsby build?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

Usually we have to execute `gatsby build` or `gatsby develop` in order to reflect the changes (made in the content at **Contentful** site), into our **Gatsby** site.

That can never be an acceptable solution, specially when there are multiple content writer, add or modifies content using the same **Contentful** account.

**How to automate the build process** so that every time someone Publish or Unpublish or Delete a content in the **Contenful** site; the **Gatsby** build will **automatically happen** and content on **Gatsby** site will **automatically gets updated**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to automate the build process so that everytime someone Publish/Unpublish content in the contenful site; the gatsby build will automatically happens and content on Gatsby site will automatically updated?

**Ans**:
Make a CI pipeline to your Gatsby codebase on GitLab and establish a connection with **Webhook** on Contetful site.

**-> How it works behind the scene:**

```
1. A webhook gets executed by calling an endpoint in GitLab, which then
2. Triggers a GitLab CI pipeline, and the
3. GitLab CI builds our static website in Gatsby, and
4. Gastby application gets the updated content from the Contentful Delivery API.
```

**-> Steps to achieve this purpose:**

**Step1: Setup a trigger URL in GitLab CI pipeline**

```
i. Go to your gitLab repo [gitlab.com/<OrganizationName>/<RepositoryName>/tree/<BranchName>]  
ii. Add the .gitlab-ci.yml file
```

*.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
image: node:latest
cache:
    paths:
      - .cache/
      - ./node_modules
      - public/
pages:
    script:
      - npm install
      - ./node_modules/.bin/gatsby build --prefix.paths
    artifacts:
        paths:
         - public
        only:
         -gitlab-ci
```

**Step2: Setup the Webhook URL**

```
i. In the same gitlab page Click on "Settings"(link on the bottom of the left menu) -> CI/CD -> Pipeline Triggers -> Expand -> Enter Description as lets say 'Ips Gatsby Build' -> Add Trigger
ii. Now note the "Token" and the url[under the "User Webhook" s.a. https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/20273592/<BranchName>/trigger/pipeline?token=<Token>]
```

**Step3: Setup the Gitlab Webhook in the Contentful**

```
i. Go to Contentful CMS site -> Settings -> Webhook -> Add Webhook -> Insert the details as below
    a. Name:  Ips Gitlab CI Trigger
    b. URL:   POST  the URL from Step1
    c. Triggers: Select Specific triggering events
            Event publish unpublish
    d. Filters: EnvId(sys.environment.sys.id) equals master
    e. Content Type: application/x-www-form-uriencoded; charset=utf-8
    f. Payload: Use default Payload
    Now click on Save
```

**Step4: Test the "Build Automation" workflow**

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [webhook](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/automate-site-builds-with-webhooks/) which essentially is what you described, an action (create, update or delete) that triggers another action (i.e: `gatsby build`) by exposing endpoints.

Its implementation will strictly rely on the hosting platform but as you mention Contentful they expose a bunch of options for different platforms (Heroku, Netlify, CircleCI, etc).

More documentation of Contentful webhooks can be found at https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/webhooks/

Comment: Thank you @Ferran Buireu, for responding. I was actually looking for the exact steps to follow. Somehow my issue got resolved, by following the steps I mentioned in the accepted answer to this question. But thank you again!